# replacing CALayer and CABasicAnimation with SKScene and SKActions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am trying to restructure this [Github Swift project](https://github.com/dabing1022/DBMetaballLoading) on Metaballs so that the circles are represented by SKShapeNodes that are moved around by SKActions instead of `CABasicAnimation`.

I am not interested in the various Metaball parameters (the handleLenRate, Spacing and so on) appearing in the viewController. I basically want to be able to specify a start and end position for the animation using SKActions.

I am not certain how to achieve this, especially how to replace the `startAnimation` function below with SKShapeNode's with SKActions:

```
    func startAnimation() {
    let loadingLayer = self.layer as! DBMetaballLoadingLayer
    loadingAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movingBallCenterX")
    loadingAnimation!.duration = 2.5
    loadingAnimation!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    loadingAnimation!.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint:fromPoint)
    loadingAnimation!.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: toPoint)
    loadingAnimation!.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    loadingAnimation!.autoreverses = true
    loadingLayer.addAnimation(loadingAnimation!, forKey: "loading")
}
```

Please see what I've been able to do below:

`MBCircle` class:

```
struct MBCircle {
var center: CGPoint = CGPointZero
var radius: CGFloat = 0.0
var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return CGRect(x: center.x - radius, y: center.y - radius, width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius)
    }
  }
}

struct DefaultConfig {
    static let radius: CGFloat = 15.0
    static let mv: CGFloat = 0.6
    static let maxDistance: CGFloat = 10 * DefaultConfig.radius
    static let handleLenRate: CGFloat = 2.0
    static let spacing: CGFloat = 160.0
}
```

`GameScene` class (representing both the `DBMetaballLoadingLayer` and `DBMetaballLoadingView`):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

private let MOVE_BALL_SCALE_RATE: CGFloat = 0.75
private let ITEM_COUNT = 2
private let SCALE_RATE: CGFloat = 1.0//0.3
private var circlePaths = [MBCircle]()
var radius: CGFloat = DefaultConfig.radius
var maxLength: CGFloat {
    get {
        return (radius * 4 + spacing) * CGFloat(ITEM_COUNT) 
    }
}
var maxDistance: CGFloat = DefaultConfig.maxDistance
var mv: CGFloat = DefaultConfig.mv
var spacing: CGFloat = DefaultConfig.spacing {
    didSet {
        _adjustSpacing(spacing)
    }
}
var handleLenRate: CGFloat = DefaultConfig.handleLenRate
var movingBallCenterX : CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        if (circlePaths.count > 0) {
            circlePaths[0].center = CGPoint(x: movingBallCenterX, y: circlePaths[0].center.y)
        }
    }
}

func _generalInit() {
    circlePaths = Array(0..<ITEM_COUNT).map { i in
        var circlePath = MBCircle()
        circlePath.center = CGPoint(x: (radius * 10 + spacing) * CGFloat(i), y: radius * (1.0 + SCALE_RATE))
        circlePath.radius = i == 0 ? radius * MOVE_BALL_SCALE_RATE : radius
        circlePath.sprite = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circlePath.radius)
        circlePath.sprite?.position = circlePath.center
        circlePath.sprite?.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        addChild(circlePath.sprite!)
        return circlePath

    }
}

func _adjustSpacing(spacing: CGFloat) {
    if (ITEM_COUNT > 1 && circlePaths.count > 1) {
        for i in 1..<ITEM_COUNT {
            var circlePath = circlePaths[i]
            circlePath.center = CGPoint(x: (radius*2 + spacing) * CGFloat(i), y: radius * (1.0 + SCALE_RATE))
        }
    }
}

func _renderPath(path: UIBezierPath) {
    var shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
    shapeNode.path = path.CGPath
    shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    addChild(shapeNode)
   }

func _metaball(j: Int, i: Int, v: CGFloat, handeLenRate: CGFloat, maxDistance: CGFloat) {
    let circle1 = circlePaths[i]
    let circle2 = circlePaths[j]

    let center1 = circle1.center
    let center2 = circle2.center

    let d = center1.distance(center2)

    var radius1 = circle1.radius
    var radius2 = circle2.radius

    if (d > maxDistance) {
        _renderPath(UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circle2.frame))

    } else {
        let scale2 = 1 + SCALE_RATE * (1 - d / maxDistance)
        radius2 *= scale2
        _renderPath(UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: circle2.center.x - radius2, y: circle2.center.y - radius2, width: 2 * radius2, height: 2 * radius2)))

    }

    if (radius1 == 0 || radius2 == 0) {
        return
    }

    var u1: CGFloat = 0.0
    var u2: CGFloat = 0.0
    if (d > maxDistance || d <= abs(radius1 - radius2)) {
        return
    } else if (d < radius1 + radius2) {
        u1 = acos((radius1 * radius1 + d * d - radius2 * radius2) / (2 * radius1 * d))
        u2 = acos((radius2 * radius2 + d * d - radius1 * radius1) / (2 * radius2 * d))
    } else {
        u1 = 0.0
        u2 = 0.0
    }

    let angle1 = center1.angleBetween(center2)
    let angle2 = acos((radius1 - radius2) / d)
    let angle1a = angle1 + u1 + (angle2 - u1) * v
    let angle1b = angle1 - u1 - (angle2 - u1) * v
    let angle2a = angle1 + CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v
    let angle2b = angle1 - CGFloat(M_PI) + u2 + (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v

    let p1a = center1.point(radians: angle1a, withLength: radius1)
    let p1b = center1.point(radians: angle1b, withLength: radius1)
    let p2a = center2.point(radians: angle2a, withLength: radius2)
    let p2b = center2.point(radians: angle2b, withLength: radius2)

    let totalRadius = radius1 + radius2
    var d2 = min(v * handeLenRate, p1a.minus(p2a).length() / totalRadius)
    d2 *= min(1, d * 2 / totalRadius)
    radius1 *= d2
    radius2 *= d2

    let cp1a = p1a.point(radians: angle1a - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)
    let cp2a = p2a.point(radians: angle2a + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
    let cp2b = p2b.point(radians: angle2b - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
    let cp1b = p1b.point(radians: angle1b + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)

    let pathJoinedCircles = UIBezierPath()
    pathJoinedCircles.moveToPoint(p1a)
    pathJoinedCircles.addCurveToPoint(p2a, controlPoint1: cp1a, controlPoint2: cp2a)
    pathJoinedCircles.addLineToPoint(p2b)
    pathJoinedCircles.addCurveToPoint(p1b, controlPoint1: cp2b, controlPoint2: cp1b)
    pathJoinedCircles.addLineToPoint(p1a)
    pathJoinedCircles.closePath()
    _renderPath(pathJoinedCircles)
}

func startAnimation() {

}
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    _generalInit()

}

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
   }
}
```

I didn't make any changes to the `CGPointExtension` class.

**UPDATE**

I am still trying to get the metaball effect, this is my progress so far based on suggestions from Alessandro Ornano:

```
import SpriteKit

extension CGPoint {
func distance(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let dx = point.x - self.x
    let dy = point.y - self.y
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
}

func angleBetween(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    return atan2(point.y - self.y, point.x - self.x)
}

func point(radians radians: CGFloat, withLength length: CGFloat) -> CGPoint   {
    return CGPoint(x: self.x + length * cos(radians), y: self.y + length * sin(radians))
}

func minus(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: self.x - point.x, y: self.y - point.y)
}

func length() -> CGFloat {
    return sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y + self.y)
}

}

class GameScene: SKScene {
var dBCircle : SKShapeNode!
let radiusDBCircle: CGFloat = 10
let radiusBall: CGFloat = 15
var balls = [SKShapeNode]()
var distanceBtwBalls : CGFloat = 15

private let SCALE_RATE: CGFloat = 0.3
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // Some parameters
    let strokeColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
    let dBHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-84 // 64 navigationController height + 20 reasonable distance
    let dBStartX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-160 // extreme left
    let dBStopX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+160 // extreme right
    let dBWidth = dBStopX - dBStartX
    let totalBalls = 7 // first and last will be hidden
    let ballArea = dBWidth / CGFloat(totalBalls-1)
    distanceBtwBalls = ((ballArea-(radiusBall*2))+radiusBall*2)

    // Create dbCircle
    dBCircle = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusDBCircle)
    dBCircle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), dBHeight)
    dBCircle.strokeColor = strokeColor
    dBCircle.name = "dBCircle"
    dBCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    addChild(dBCircle)


    // Make static balls
    for i in 0..<totalBalls {
        let ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusBall)
        ball.position =   CGPointMake(dBStartX+(distanceBtwBalls*CGFloat(i)), dBHeight)
        ball.strokeColor = strokeColor
        ball.name = "ball"
        ball.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        balls.append(ball)
        if i == 0 || i == totalBalls-1 {
            ball.hidden = true
        }
        addChild(ball)
    }
    mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(dBCircle,dBStartX: dBStartX,dBStopX: dBStopX)
}
func mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(node:SKShapeNode,dBStartX:CGFloat,dBStopX:CGFloat) {
    let actionMoveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(dBStartX, duration:1.7)
    actionMoveLeft.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

    let actionMoveRight = SKAction.moveToX(dBStopX, duration:1.7)
    actionMoveRight.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionMoveLeft,actionMoveRight])))
}
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    var i = 0
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("ball") {
        node, stop in
        let ball = node as! SKShapeNode

        if CGRectContainsRect(ball.frame, self.dBCircle.frame) {
            if (ball.actionForKey("zoom") == nil) {

                let zoomIn = SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 0.25)
                let zoomOut = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.25)
                let seq = SKAction.sequence([zoomIn,zoomOut])
                ball.runAction(seq,withKey: "zoom")
            }
        }
        i += 1
    }
    movingBeziers()
}

func _renderPath(path: UIBezierPath) {
    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path.CGPath)
    shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    addChild(shapeNode)

}

func movingBeziers()    {
    _renderPath(UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: dBCircle.frame))
    for j in 1..<balls.count {
    self.latestTestMetaball(j, circleShape: dBCircle, v: 0.6, handleLenRate:  2.0, maxDistance: self.distanceBtwBalls)
    }
}

func latestTestMetaball (j: Int, circleShape: SKShapeNode, v: CGFloat, handleLenRate: CGFloat, maxDistance: CGFloat)    {
    let circle1 = circleShape
    let circle2 = balls[j]

    let center1 = circle1.position
    let center2 = circle2.position

    let d = center1.distance(center2)

    var radius1 = circle1.frame.width
    var radius2 = circle2.frame.width


    var u1: CGFloat = 0.0
    var u2: CGFloat = 0.0
    if (d > maxDistance || d <= abs(radius1 - radius2)) {
        return
    } else if (d < radius1 + radius2) {
        u1 = acos((radius1 * radius1 + d * d - radius2 * radius2) / (2 * radius1 * d))
        u2 = acos((radius2 * radius2 + d * d - radius1 * radius1) / (2 * radius2 * d))
    } else {
        u1 = 0.0
        u2 = 0.0
    }

    let angle1 = center1.angleBetween(center2)
    let angle2 = acos((radius1 - radius2) / d)
    let angle1a = angle1 + u1 + (angle2 - u1) * v
    let angle1b = angle1 - u1 - (angle2 - u1) * v
    let angle2a = angle1 + CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v
    let angle2b = angle1 - CGFloat(M_PI) + u2 + (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v

    let p1a = center1.point(radians: angle1a, withLength: radius1)
    let p1b = center1.point(radians: angle1b, withLength: radius1)
    let p2a = center2.point(radians: angle2a, withLength: radius2)
    let p2b = center2.point(radians: angle2b, withLength: radius2)

    let totalRadius = radius1 + radius2
    var d2 = min(v * handleLenRate, p1a.minus(p2a).length() / totalRadius)
    d2 *= min(1, d * 2 / totalRadius)
    radius1 *= d2
    radius2 *= d2

    let cp1a = p1a.point(radians: angle1a - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)
    let cp2a = p2a.point(radians: angle2a + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
    let cp2b = p2b.point(radians: angle2b - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
    let cp1b = p1b.point(radians: angle1b + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)

    let pathJoinedCircles = UIBezierPath()
    pathJoinedCircles.moveToPoint(p1a)
    pathJoinedCircles.addCurveToPoint(p2a, controlPoint1: cp1a, controlPoint2: cp2a)
    pathJoinedCircles.addLineToPoint(p2b)
    pathJoinedCircles.addCurveToPoint(p1b, controlPoint1: cp2b, controlPoint2: cp1b)
    pathJoinedCircles.addLineToPoint(p1a)
    pathJoinedCircles.closePath()
    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: pathJoinedCircles.CGPath)
    shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    addChild(shapeNode)
  }
}
```

Comment: Someone told me to tell you that you might find my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31502698/2158465 to be helpful. I have no idea if it will be as I haven't read your entire question yet. Just figured I let you know on the off chance that it helps.

Comment: @EpicByte the questions don't really seem to be related in my opinion. My understanding from the person's comment is they wanted you to see if you could contribute or find a solution to my question.

Comment: @EpicByte the guy believes you can solve it

Comment: I wouldn't do this until somebody verifies the SKShapeNode bugs are fixed in iOS 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily achieve this kind of animation using `moveToX` and the `timingMode` [parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKAction/timingMode).

New **Swift 3** translation below at the end of this answer.

To make an example I use the Xcode Sprite-Kit *"Hello, World!"* official project demo:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
        myLabel.fontSize = 15
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(myLabel)
        mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(myLabel)
    }
    func mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(node:SKLabelNode) {
        let actionMoveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-100, duration:1.5)
        actionMoveLeft.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        let actionMoveRight = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+100, duration:1.5)
        actionMoveRight.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionMoveLeft,actionMoveRight])))
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Update** (This part start to emulate the static ball and the dynamic ball moving left and right but without metaball animations)

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var dBCircle : SKShapeNode!
    let radiusDBCircle: CGFloat = 10
    let radiusBall: CGFloat = 15
    private let SCALE_RATE: CGFloat = 0.3
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // Some parameters
        let strokeColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        let dBHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-84 // 64 navigationController height + 20 reasonable distance
        let dBStartX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-160 // extreme left
        let dBStopX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+160 // extreme right
        let dBWidth = dBStopX - dBStartX
        let totalBalls = 7 // first and last will be hidden
        let ballArea = dBWidth / CGFloat(totalBalls-1)
        let distanceBtwBalls = ((ballArea-(radiusBall*2))+radiusBall*2)

        // Create dbCircle
        dBCircle = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusDBCircle)
        dBCircle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), dBHeight)
        dBCircle.strokeColor = strokeColor
        dBCircle.name = "dBCircle"
        dBCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        addChild(dBCircle)
        // Make static balls
        for i in 0..<totalBalls {
            let ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusBall)
            ball.position =   CGPointMake(dBStartX+(distanceBtwBalls*CGFloat(i)), dBHeight)
            ball.strokeColor = strokeColor
            ball.name = "ball"
            ball.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            if i == 0 || i == totalBalls-1 {
                ball.hidden = true
            }
            addChild(ball)
        }
        mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(dBCircle,dBStartX: dBStartX,dBStopX: dBStopX)
    }
    func mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(node:SKShapeNode,dBStartX:CGFloat,dBStopX:CGFloat) {
        let actionMoveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(dBStartX, duration:1.7)
        actionMoveLeft.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        let actionMoveRight = SKAction.moveToX(dBStopX, duration:1.7)
        actionMoveRight.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionMoveLeft,actionMoveRight])))
    }
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        var i = 0
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("ball") {
            node, stop in
            let ball = node as! SKShapeNode

            if CGRectContainsRect(ball.frame, self.dBCircle.frame) {
                if (ball.actionForKey("zoom") == nil) {
                    let zoomIn = SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 0.25)
                    let zoomOut = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.25)
                    let seq = SKAction.sequence([zoomIn,zoomOut])
                    ball.runAction(seq,withKey: "zoom")
                }
            }
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

### **New update with metaball animation**:

Finally I've realize this result, my goal is to make it very similar to the original :

[image]

is it possible to make some variations to times (for example zoomIn or zoomOut time values or actionMoveLeft, actionMoveRight time values), this is the code:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var dBCircle : SKShapeNode!
    let radiusDBCircle: CGFloat = 10
    let radiusBall: CGFloat = 15
    private let SCALE_RATE: CGFloat = 0.3
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // Some parameters
        let strokeColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        let dBHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-84 // 64 navigationController height + 20 reasonable distance
        let dBStartX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-160 // extreme left
        let dBStopX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+160 // extreme right
        let dBWidth = dBStopX - dBStartX
        let totalBalls = 7 // first and last will be hidden
        let ballArea = dBWidth / CGFloat(totalBalls-1)
        let distanceBtwBalls = ((ballArea-(radiusBall*2))+radiusBall*2)

        // Create dbCircle
        dBCircle = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusDBCircle)
        dBCircle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), dBHeight)
        dBCircle.strokeColor = strokeColor
        dBCircle.name = "dBCircle"
        dBCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        addChild(dBCircle)
        // Make static balls
        for i in 0..<totalBalls {
            let ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusBall)
            ball.position =   CGPointMake(dBStartX+(distanceBtwBalls*CGFloat(i)), dBHeight)
            ball.strokeColor = strokeColor
            ball.name = "ball"
            ball.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            if i == 0 || i == totalBalls-1 {
                ball.hidden = true
            }
            addChild(ball)
        }
        mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(dBCircle,dBStartX: dBStartX,dBStopX: dBStopX)
    }
    func mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(node:SKShapeNode,dBStartX:CGFloat,dBStopX:CGFloat) {
        let actionMoveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(dBStartX, duration:2.5)
        actionMoveLeft.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        let actionMoveRight = SKAction.moveToX(dBStopX, duration:2.5)
        actionMoveRight.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut

        node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionMoveLeft,actionMoveRight])))
    }
    //MARK: - _metaball original function
    func _metaball(circle2:SKShapeNode, circle1:SKShapeNode, v: CGFloat, handeLenRate: CGFloat, maxDistance: CGFloat,vanishingTime : NSTimeInterval = 0.015) {
        let center1 = circle1.position
        let center2 = circle2.position
        let d = center1.distance(center2)
        var radius1 = radiusDBCircle
        var radius2 = radiusBall
        if (radius1 == 0 || radius2 == 0) {
            return
        }
        var u1: CGFloat = 0.0
        var u2: CGFloat = 0.0
        if (d > maxDistance || d <= abs(radius1 - radius2)) {
            return
        } else if (d < radius1 + radius2) {
            u1 = acos((radius1 * radius1 + d * d - radius2 * radius2) / (2 * radius1 * d))
            u2 = acos((radius2 * radius2 + d * d - radius1 * radius1) / (2 * radius2 * d))
        } else {
            u1 = 0.0
            u2 = 0.0
        }
        let angle1 = center1.angleBetween(center2)
        let angle2 = acos((radius1 - radius2) / d)
        let angle1a = angle1 + u1 + (angle2 - u1) * v
        let angle1b = angle1 - u1 - (angle2 - u1) * v
        let angle2a = angle1 + CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v
        let angle2b = angle1 - CGFloat(M_PI) + u2 + (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v
        let p1a = center1.point(radians: angle1a, withLength: radius1)
        let p1b = center1.point(radians: angle1b, withLength: radius1)
        let p2a = center2.point(radians: angle2a, withLength: radius2)
        let p2b = center2.point(radians: angle2b, withLength: radius2)
        let totalRadius = radius1 + radius2
        var d2 = min(v * handeLenRate, p1a.minus(p2a).length() / totalRadius)
        d2 *= min(1, d * 2 / totalRadius)
        radius1 *= d2
        radius2 *= d2
        let cp1a = p1a.point(radians: angle1a - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)
        let cp2a = p2a.point(radians: angle2a + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
        let cp2b = p2b.point(radians: angle2b - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
        let cp1b = p1b.point(radians: angle1b + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)
        let pathJoinedCircles = UIBezierPath()
        pathJoinedCircles.moveToPoint(p1a)
        pathJoinedCircles.addCurveToPoint(p2a, controlPoint1: cp1a, controlPoint2: cp2a)
        pathJoinedCircles.addLineToPoint(p2b)
        pathJoinedCircles.addCurveToPoint(p1b, controlPoint1: cp2b, controlPoint2: cp1b)
        pathJoinedCircles.addLineToPoint(p1a)
        pathJoinedCircles.closePath()
        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: pathJoinedCircles.CGPath)
        shapeNode.strokeColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        addChild(shapeNode)
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(vanishingTime)
        self.runAction(wait,completion: {
            shapeNode.removeFromParent()
        })
    }
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        var i = 0
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("ball") {
            node, stop in
            let ball = node as! SKShapeNode
            let enlargeFrame = CGRectMake(ball.frame.origin.x-self.radiusBall*3,ball.frame.origin.y,ball.frame.width+(self.radiusBall*6),ball.frame.height)
            if CGRectContainsRect(enlargeFrame, self.dBCircle.frame) {
                if (ball.actionForKey("zoom") == nil) {
                    let zoomIn = SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 0.25)
                    zoomIn.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut
                    let zoomOut = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.25)
                    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.8)
                    let seq = SKAction.sequence([zoomIn,zoomOut,wait])
                    ball.runAction(seq,withKey: "zoom")
                }
            }
            self._metaball(ball, circle1: self.dBCircle, v: 0.6, handeLenRate: 2.0, maxDistance: 4 * self.radiusBall)
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
//MARK: - Extensions
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let dx = point.x - self.x
        let dy = point.y - self.y
        return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    }
    func angleBetween(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(point.y - self.y, point.x - self.x)
    }
    func point(radians radians: CGFloat, withLength length: CGFloat) -> CGPoint   {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x + length * cos(radians), y: self.y + length * sin(radians))
    }
    func minus(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x - point.x, y: self.y - point.y)
    }
    func length() -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y + self.y)
    }
}
```

### Swift 3:

(I've made a little change to `maxDistance: 4 * self.radiusBall` with `maxDistance: 5 * self.radiusBall` to become more similar to the original but you can change it as you wish)

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var dBCircle : SKShapeNode!
    let radiusDBCircle: CGFloat = 10
    let radiusBall: CGFloat = 15
    private let SCALE_RATE: CGFloat = 0.3
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let label = self.childNode(withName: "//helloLabel") as? SKLabelNode
        label?.removeFromParent()
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        // Some parameters
        let strokeColor = SKColor.orange
        let dBHeight = self.frame.midY
        let dBStartX = self.frame.midX-260 // extreme left
        let dBStopX = self.frame.midX+260 // extreme right
        let dBWidth = dBStopX - dBStartX
        let totalBalls = 7 // first and last will be hidden
        let ballArea = dBWidth / CGFloat(totalBalls-1)
        let distanceBtwBalls = ((ballArea-(radiusBall*2))+radiusBall*2)

        // Create dbCircle
        dBCircle = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusDBCircle)
        dBCircle.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:dBHeight)
        dBCircle.strokeColor = strokeColor
        dBCircle.name = "dBCircle"
        dBCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear
        addChild(dBCircle)
        // Make static balls
        for i in 0..<totalBalls {
            let ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radiusBall)
            ball.position =   CGPoint(x:dBStartX+(distanceBtwBalls*CGFloat(i)), y:dBHeight)
            ball.strokeColor = strokeColor
            ball.name = "ball"
            ball.fillColor = UIColor.clear
            if i == 0 || i == totalBalls-1 {
                ball.isHidden = true
            }
            addChild(ball)
        }
        mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(node: dBCircle,dBStartX: dBStartX,dBStopX: dBStopX)
    }
    func mediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOutEmulate(node:SKShapeNode,dBStartX:CGFloat,dBStopX:CGFloat) {
        let actionMoveLeft = SKAction.moveTo(x: dBStartX, duration:2.5)
        actionMoveLeft.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut

        let actionMoveRight = SKAction.moveTo(x: dBStopX, duration:2.5)
        actionMoveRight.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut

        node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([actionMoveLeft,actionMoveRight])))
    }
    //MARK: - _metaball original function
    func _metaball(circle2:SKShapeNode, circle1:SKShapeNode, v: CGFloat, handeLenRate: CGFloat, maxDistance: CGFloat,vanishingTime : TimeInterval = 0.015) {
        let center1 = circle1.position
        let center2 = circle2.position
        let d = center1.distance(point: center2)
        var radius1 = radiusDBCircle
        var radius2 = radiusBall
        if (radius1 == 0 || radius2 == 0) {
            return
        }
        var u1: CGFloat = 0.0
        var u2: CGFloat = 0.0
        if (d > maxDistance || d <= abs(radius1 - radius2)) {
            return
        } else if (d < radius1 + radius2) {
            u1 = acos((radius1 * radius1 + d * d - radius2 * radius2) / (2 * radius1 * d))
            u2 = acos((radius2 * radius2 + d * d - radius1 * radius1) / (2 * radius2 * d))
        } else {
            u1 = 0.0
            u2 = 0.0
        }
        let angle1 = center1.angleBetween(point: center2)
        let angle2 = acos((radius1 - radius2) / d)
        let angle1a = angle1 + u1 + (angle2 - u1) * v
        let angle1b = angle1 - u1 - (angle2 - u1) * v
        let angle2a = angle1 + CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v
        let angle2b = angle1 - CGFloat(M_PI) + u2 + (CGFloat(M_PI) - u2 - angle2) * v
        let p1a = center1.point(radians: angle1a, withLength: radius1)
        let p1b = center1.point(radians: angle1b, withLength: radius1)
        let p2a = center2.point(radians: angle2a, withLength: radius2)
        let p2b = center2.point(radians: angle2b, withLength: radius2)
        let totalRadius = radius1 + radius2
        var d2 = min(v * handeLenRate, p1a.minus(point: p2a).length() / totalRadius)
        d2 *= min(1, d * 2 / totalRadius)
        radius1 *= d2
        radius2 *= d2
        let cp1a = p1a.point(radians: angle1a - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)
        let cp2a = p2a.point(radians: angle2a + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
        let cp2b = p2b.point(radians: angle2b - CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius2)
        let cp1b = p1b.point(radians: angle1b + CGFloat(M_PI_2), withLength: radius1)
        let pathJoinedCircles = UIBezierPath()
        pathJoinedCircles.move(to: p1a)
        pathJoinedCircles.addCurve(to: p2a, controlPoint1: cp1a, controlPoint2: cp2a)
        pathJoinedCircles.addLine(to: p2b)
        pathJoinedCircles.addCurve(to: p1b, controlPoint1: cp2b, controlPoint2: cp1b)
        pathJoinedCircles.addLine(to: p1a)
        pathJoinedCircles.close()
        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: pathJoinedCircles.cgPath)
        shapeNode.strokeColor = SKColor.orange
        shapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.clear
        addChild(shapeNode)
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: vanishingTime)
        self.run(wait,completion: {
            shapeNode.removeFromParent()
        })
    }
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        var i = 0
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ball") {
            node, stop in
            let ball = node as! SKShapeNode
            let enlargeFrame = CGRect(x:ball.frame.origin.x-self.radiusBall*3,y:ball.frame.origin.y,width:ball.frame.width+(self.radiusBall*6),height:ball.frame.height)
            if enlargeFrame.contains(self.dBCircle.frame) {
                if (ball.action(forKey: "zoom") == nil) {
                    let zoomIn = SKAction.scale(to: 1.5, duration: 0.25)
                    zoomIn.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut
                    let zoomOut = SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.25)
                    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.7)
                    let seq = SKAction.sequence([zoomIn,zoomOut,wait])
                    ball.run(seq,withKey: "zoom")
                }
            }
            self._metaball(circle2: ball, circle1: self.dBCircle, v: 0.6, handeLenRate: 2.0, maxDistance: 5 * self.radiusBall)
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
//MARK: - Extensions
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let dx = point.x - self.x
        let dy = point.y - self.y
        return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    }
    func angleBetween(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return atan2(point.y - self.y, point.x - self.x)
    }
    func point(radians: CGFloat, withLength length: CGFloat) -> CGPoint   {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x + length * cos(radians), y: self.y + length * sin(radians))
    }
    func minus(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.x - point.x, y: self.y - point.y)
    }
    func length() -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y + self.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. Thanks, the movement is working perfectly but the metaball effect isn't working. only the circles appear without the stretching metaball effect.

Comment: Apologize, In the first time Ive understood you're not interested to metaballs animations or behavior, I will try to update my answer

Comment: Actually, it's the metaball view controller with slider parameters that I am not interested.

Comment: Ok, so you want to realize the metaballs animations during the horizontal bouncing right?

Comment: Hi man, this evening i've seen your project, I've solve part of the animation: the circle with all balls zooming in and out when ball pass through these objects but the last part of "metaballs" is a UIBeizerPath that require too many time. There is a function called _metaball that make these UIBeizerPath, I think it could be re-adapted to make a SKShapeNode to show and hide during the animation in the new update method I've reported.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, re-adapting the _metaball function is not small task. I would be grateful if you could provide me with some guidelines to achieve it.

Comment: No, don't remake all metaball function, just re-adapt the same UIKit included in the original project, it makes a uiBeizerPath and you can make a SKShapeNode with this path to reply the same object. There arent guidelines, you must try to import this function in a blank project and step by step look how to make the shape with this path

Comment: I have made some progress based on your suggestion, but it's still quite far from what the metaball effect I desire. Please take a look at the updated code I added to the question.

Comment: Have you been able to make any further progress? I was trying something similar a while ago but didn't make much progress. This requires a lot of patience and try and error to get the SKActions to give the same effect

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano This issue seems to be me common than I thought, someone has just put a 100 point bounty on it

Comment: Nice to know, its near to a work on commission so its reasonable to put a bounty

Comment: @chronos No, I'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Do you think combining CABasicAnimation for the metaball effect and SKActions (as you have done above) for the movement and enlarging circles is feasible?

Comment: @NSSwift No, I think you could use the already maded function called _metaball (function inside the original project) to re-make the CGPaths (from the UIBeizerPaths) which serve to generate the metaball animations (for example by making SKShapeNode for the new CGPaths).In fact if you draw the paths generated by the original _metaball function, you can see the typical hourglasses shapes created by the animations.It takes time and patience but finally you should be able to generate the same animation.It's a medium difficulty: i'd like to see someone who realizes all with SKPhysicBody :)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Wow, doing this with SKPhysicsBody would be really tough. Yeah, working with the original _metabal function UIBezierPaths would really help. I just tried OnlyCodeMatters updated code. I see the shapes, but they have to be adjusted with SKActions though. You seem to have made some headway with this one, what prevents you from just claiming the prize :)? Or you're still putting it together?

Comment: @NSSwift Now I'm busy with another project at work :( because this thread requires more time than expected, but if I see that no one accomplishes this question, I will try to solve it or to help someone.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano if you have any plans of solving it, I recommend you do before the bounty ends :)

Comment: Ok I've finish, there is a new part "New update with metaball animation", hope help someone who follow this thread to achieve this animation, good luck.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano please can we chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128319/room-for-onlycodematters-and-alessandro-ornano

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I would really be grateful if we could chat briefly, that is at your convenience. Please let me know when http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128319/room-for-onlycodematters-and-alessandro-ornano

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your question is how to replicate the same behaviour with nodes and SKAction, I believe this should do it.

```
var shapeNode : SKNode?

func startAnimation(){

    if let node = self.shapeNode {
        //assume that we have a node initialized at some point and added to the scene at some x1,y1 coordinates

        /// we define parameters for the animation
        let positionToReach = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) /// some random position
        let currentPosition = node.position /// we need the current position to be able to reverse the "animation"
        let animationDuration = 2.5 //loadingAnimation!.duration = 2.5

        /// we define which actions will be run for the node
        let actionForward = SKAction.moveTo(positionToReach, duration: animationDuration)
        let actionBackwards = SKAction.moveTo(currentPosition, duration: animationDuration)

        // we needed two actions to simulate loadingAnimation!.autoreverses = true

        /// we wrap the actions in a sequence of actions
        let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([actionForward, actionBackwards]) /// animations to repeat

        /// we want to repeat the animation forever
        let actionToRepeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(actionSequence) ///loadingAnimation!.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        /// showtime
        node.runAction(actionToRepeat)

    }

}
```

Let me know if I need to update any part as I haven't tested it. You still need to use your actual values and objects.

I have referred to referred to [How would I repeat an action forever in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915390/how-would-i-repeat-an-action-forever-in-swift) while making this reply.