# SpriteKit SKScene not reloading

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have the following menu scenes hierarchy in my game:
GameLogoScene->MainMenuScene(click play)->GameLevelScene->(click level1)->GamePlayScene

The first scene (GameLogoScene) is setup in the GameViewController class as follows:

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as? SKView

    if skView?.scene == nil  {
        skView?.showsFPS = true
        skView?.showsNodeCount = true
        skView?.showsPhysics = true
        skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

        let gameLogoScene = GameLogoScene(size: skView!.bounds.size)
        gameLogoScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView?.presentScene(gameLogoScene)
    }
}
```

In the GameLogoScene I change to the next scene (MainMenuScene) using the code below:

```
let mainMenuScene = MainMenuScene(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(mainMenuScene)
```

A similar change is made to the GameLevelScene. Then in the GameLevelScene I change to the GamePlayScene in the following way:

```
let gamePlayScene = GamePlayScene(size: self.size, levelName:.level1)
self.view?.presentScene(gamePlayScene)
```

When the win condition is satisfied a change over to the GameOverScene is made in the following way:

```
if hasWon {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.removeAllActions()
    let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.frame.size, playerWon: true, score:score.currentScore, currentLevel:currentLevel)
    scene?.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene)
    }
```

In the GameOverScene a next level button is suppose to reload the GamePlayScene but instead of reloading or resetting the scene with a new level, gameplay of the just completed level continues. Please see code below:

```
if nextLevelButton.containsPoint(location){
     let nextGameLevelScene = GamePlayScene(size: self.size, levelName:.level2)
     self.view?.presentScene(nextGameLevelScene)
        }
```

What is causing this behaviour and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

Here is relevant code from the GamePlayScene:

```
class GamePlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

init(size: CGSize, levelName: LevelName ) {

super.init(size: size)
currentLevel = levelName
switch levelName    {
case .level1:

    print("level1")
    var spriteSpeed = 1
    createMultiSprites([sSprite, mSprite, sSprite, sSprite, mSprite, lSprite, xlSprite], positions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]) 

    createMultiEnemies([lEnemySprite, lEnemySprite, xlEnemySprite], positions: [0,3, 5])



case .level2:
   var spriteSpeed = 2
   print("level2")
   createMultiSprites([xlSprite, xlSprite, xlSprite], positions: [5, 6, 7]) 

   createMultiEnemies([lEnemySprite, lEnemySprite, xlEnemySprite, xlEnemySprite ], positions: [0, 3, 5, 7])

case .level3:
    var spriteSpeed = 3
   print("level3")

   createMultiSprites([mSprite, xlSprite, mSprite, mSprite, mSprite], positions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]) 

   createMultiEnemies([xlEnemySprite, xlEnemySprite, xxlEnemySprite], positions: [0,3, 5])
      }

   movement()
    }
 }
```

Also my sSprite,..,xxlSprite and sEnemySprite,...,xxlEnemySprite don't inherit from the SKSpriteNode but have SKSpriteNode properties. For example, the SKSpriteNode for sSprite is sSprite.sprite.

Comment: are you sure the button is even being called, and are you sure that self.view is nil?  You should only use the ? when you expect a nil to be a valid option and continue.  In your case, you want to use ! so that when it is nil, it crashes and you can fix it

Comment: yeah, the button is called. I changed from the "?" to "!" but I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Can you show some code from GamePlayScene?. Your scene loading is correct so there must be an error with how you load level 2 (passed in the init of GamePlayScene). Without that code there is not much help we can give.

Comment: Hey, sorry but can you clarify what is happening. Looking at your code everything should work. I dont understand what you mean by gameplay just continues when you go back to GamePlayScene? A scene should start in a fresh state once you transition to it. Do you mean that the level 1 enum is called instead of level 2?

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it. I just realised that there were some arrays that I didn't remove, that made the the sSprites,...,xxlSprites keep remain the same though the level had changed. But still I thought that removing all children and actions would have taken care of that.

Comment: @Knight0fDragonI would be grateful if you could please take a look at this question for me, someone just put a bounty of 100 on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525232/replacing-calayer-and-cabasicanimation-with-skscene-and-skactions